# Is it possible to customize the toolbar of embedded views?

Tags: tableau-api

When I embedd a view via iframe and activate the toolbar, it looks like this by default:

[image]

**Is it possible to customize that views toolbar?** In my case, I would like to have only the download button ("Herunterladen") and probably also the full screen (Vollbild).

Comment: The Tableau JavaScript API gives you some options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize the toolbars BUT you CAN use the JavaScript API to make your own toolbar that behaves the way you'd like.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm

Comment: Could you point me to the relevant documentation / add a code sample, please?

Comment: I added a link to the help for the JavaScript API. So for your case, you can design whatever controls you like with HTML for instance, style them as desired, and use the JavaScript API to add the behavior you choose.

Comment: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_ref.htm#Toolbar_State_Example is a better link

Comment: The link in the answer points to a page that has a table of contents at the top, that then leads to different sections about the API, concepts, tutorial, reference etc. the tutorial is quick and clear. The last link in the comment is just one of those sections.